# How to get reflection and shadow in VRML.How to get reflection and shadow in VRML

Tags: reflection, vrml

I am using 3ds Max for modeling and then export it to VRML. Presently I am getting shaders,texture and material.
Is any method to get reflection and shadows in VRML?

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 0):

VRML does not support shadows or reflections (and neither does its successor, X3D, although there are proprietary extensions that do.